# Converting Unix Timestamp into a Custom Human Readable time using mySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following table in a MySQL database:

```
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| id       | firstName           | lastName        | tstamp        |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 133      | James               | Mosher          | 1589470887919 |  
| 145      | Bill                | Turner          | 1589470888235 | 
| 146      | Jeremy              | Vine            | 1589470888592 |  
| 152      | Ramon               | Jesus           | 1589470889319 |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I want to be able to see the **tstamp** column in a human readable date time format.
I tried the following query but it didn't work and gave me a blank column. Anyone has any idea or see what I am doing wrong?

`SELECT id, firstName, lastName, tstamp, FROM_UNIXTIME(tstamp, '%Y %D %M %H:%i:%s') AS timeAndDate FROM students;`

Result:

```
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| id       | firstName           | lastName        | tstamp        | timeAndDate   |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 133      | James               | Mosher          | 1589470887919 |               | 
| 145      | Bill                | Turner          | 1589470888235 |               |
| 146      | Jeremy              | Vine            | 1589470888592 |               |
| 152      | Ramon               | Jesus           | 1589470889319 |               |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Example -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nfSnTKfNYdBcbs8pDgbcdQ/0

Comment: FWIW, I would handle this in application code, formatting the time to suit the locale of the reader

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes, you are right but I do not own the application code that generates this. Only have MySql access to data for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamps contain milliseconds.
You can remove them if you divide by 1000:

```
SELECT id, firstName, lastName, tstamp, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(tstamp / 1000, '%Y %D %M %H:%i:%s') AS timeAndDate 
FROM myTable;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7aYgPjb2ZcMd8QwJj4wK8/0).

Answer (score 1):

See comments, but I guess you're after something like this...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1589470887919/1000),'%Y %d %m %H:%i:%s') x;
+---------------------+
| x                   |
+---------------------+
| 2020 14 05 16:41:27 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: There is no need for DATE_FORMAT(). The function FROM_UNIXTIME() takes the format as the 2nd argument.

Comment: @forpas - oh, right - good to know; thanks, that's much more elegant!